# How to remove the title entirely from Kivy popup (using Python not .kv)?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a Kivy popup that has an 'x' button in the top left corner to close the popup. I created the button and this functionality, and it is in the top left but not the *very top left*.

See image of popup here

[image]

I am running into problems with the `Popup.title` . It seems that title_size only changes the size of the font of the text in the title, not the title itself. Do you know of a way to change the the title so my button can be in the top-most left corner?

```
import sys
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout #for popup 'x' button
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inside = BoxLayout(spacing = 10)
        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.btn2 = Button(text="Open popup", size_hint=(.5, .3))

        self.btn2.bind(on_press=self.workscreen)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

        content = RelativeLayout()
        content_cancel = Button(text='x', 
                        pos_hint={'left': 1, 'top': 1}, 
                        size_hint=(.1, .1),
                        background_normal='',
                        background_color=(0, 0.4, 1, 1))
        content.add_widget(content_cancel)
        content.add_widget(Label(text="This is some helpful text."))
        self.popup = Popup(title='', separator_height=0,
                    #content=Button(text='Close me!', pos_hint={'left': 1, 'top': 1}),
                    title_size=0, 
                    content=content,
                    auto_dismiss=False,
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

        content_cancel.bind(on_press=self.popup.dismiss) #for popup 'x' button

    def workscreen(self, instance):
        self.popup.open()


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.root = root = RootWidget()
        root.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

        with root.canvas.before:
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=root.size, pos=root.pos)
        return root

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__()` method you can add:

```
    title_label = self.popup.children[0].children[2]
    title_label.height = 0
```

just after the line that creates the `Popup`. This is a really ugly hack and may fail if the `Popup` class is ever changed by a `Kivy` update.